# Nuxt.js - How to load plugins in component

Tags: vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

I have  `google-oauth.js` plugin in nuxt application. I load the plugin in `nuxt.config.js` file.

```
plugins: [
        { src: '@plugins/google-oauth.js', ssr: false }
   ],
```

and it works fine.
But this loads the plugin before the app mounted. I need it only in 1 component .

## 1. So is there is any way to load the plugin , once the app fully mounted or in that component only?

I tried the following in component page

```
export default {
  plugins: [{ src: '@plugins/google-oauth.js', ssr: false }],
  components: {
     CreateEmail
  },
/*  */
}
```

but it doesn't load the page.

## 2. Also , is there any way to load the design only in login page in the app, and mount the app once login loaded.